# How to determine the file size for multi-part POST request Java?

Tags: java, rest

I want to determine the size of a file in a POST request before it is processed in my backend. Consider

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response uploadFile(
        @FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream,
        @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail) throws IOException {
         String uploadedFileLocation = "somePath" + fileDetail.getFileName();
        // save it
    writeToFile(uploadedInputStream, uploadedFileLocation);
    String output = "File uploaded to : " + uploadedFileLocation;
    return Response.ok(output).build();
}

// save uploaded file to new location
private void writeToFile(InputStream uploadedInputStream, String uploadedFileLocation) throws IOException {
    int read;
    final int BUFFER_LENGTH = 1024;
    final byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_LENGTH];
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(uploadedFileLocation));
    while ((read = uploadedInputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        out.write(buffer, 0, read);
    }
    out.flush();
    out.close();
}
```

I saw I can use the Content-Disposition to get the file size. how can I get the Content-Disposition header to get the length  or should there be a function that checks the size of the input stream?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `@HeaderParam` to get the value of a named header.

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response uploadFile(
    @FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream,
    @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail,
    @HeaderParam("Content-Disposition") String contentDisposition
) throws IOException {
```

Note that you still need to add the file size to the header in the client side, assuming you're using something like the DOM File API and fetch.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately the client side can not provide the  Content-Disposition. Is there away I can catch the input Stream before the whole file reaches the backend without changing the client side

Comment: The only best guess is to read the `Content-Length` which may not even always be present and even then it's the size of the whole multipart data, usually encoded in base-64. If your client-side uploads the file using Javascript, you could get the file size there and append it to the `Content-Disposition` header or some other header.

Comment: Hmm thanks, unfortunately I do not have a Javascript on my client side (,yet). Is there way the stop the input stream to the backend before it is persisted on the backend?

Comment: You can either read the file to memory and run checks on it, or if it's only a file size check, you should configure that in the web server's configuration for the HTTP POST payload size or alternatively do what Abdullah G suggested. Honestly, your server configuration should absolutely anyways have a set limit for the HTTP request size.

Comment: Do have any idea how in Dropwizard the server configuration is set to limit the upload size. Dropwizard is  using Jersey with the  JAX-RS implementation.

Comment: @A.Dumas Some google-fu leads to a few solutions: https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/issues/1657

Answer (score 0):

You should count buffer size.

```
.... 
int size=0;

while ((read = uploadedInputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    out.write(buffer, 0, read);
    size += read.length;
}
System.out.println("size : "+size);
```

Comment: The asker wants to get the size *before* processing the data.

Comment: Also asker can get file size from client side and post size parameter to server

Comment: Thanks for the response. Is the file size checked while the file is uploaded? or must the file be on the backend before the size can be checked.